# ElasticSearch Hitboosting

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

Im looking for a way to perform some sort of hitboosting on search results, so that results that are clicked more frequently appears higher on the list.

Im thinking about storing a document in a different index (ex. "`click_statistics`" everytime someone clicks on a result, store a new document with the `_id` of the search result clicked as a field. This seems like a suitable way of doing it, and it helps me keep the statistics even when re-indexing the main index. (If you have any other suggestions, please share)

But i have no idea on how i can combine the count from the second index, and then include some sort of scoring based on that count to the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way in which you could do this is to include a field on each document that contains the number of clicks it has had, and use a [`function_score` query with a `field_value_factor` function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) that scores based on some function of the click number

```cs
public class MyDocument
{
    public long Clicks { get; set; } 
}

var response = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .FunctionScore(fs => fs
            .Query(fq => fq
                // your search query here
                .MatchAll()
            )
            .Functions(fun => fun
                // boost by a factor of the square root of the click value 
                // for documents with clicks greater than 0
                .FieldValueFactor(fvf => fvf
                    .Field(f => f.Clicks)
                    .Filter(fi => fi
                        .Range(r => r
                            .Field(rf => rf.Clicks)
                            .GreaterThan(0)
                        )
                    )
                    .Factor(1.5)
                    .Modifier(FieldValueFactorModifier.SquareRoot)
                )
            )
            .ScoreMode(FunctionScoreMode.Multiply)
        )
    )
);
```

If you'd like to aggregate and analyze click statistics, then it's a good idea to also store them in an index.

Depending on the frequency of clicks, it's probably a good idea **not** to update the click counts on documents every time a click happens; perhaps it makes sense to update them hourly, daily, weekly, in the quiet time (if you have one), etc. You could use the click statistics index along with a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the clicked document id field to get the counts of clicks for each document in your chosen timeframe, then use the [`bulk` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update) to update all clicked documents in the search index.

Comment: Thats my general idea for now as well, tracking clicks and aggregate and update the original docs with interval X. I just tought that there may be a way to to it all on each query (like a JOIN, and then do a function score) - but that might be terribly ineffective, and might be a bigger performance loss just to get "real-time" data. if at all possible.

Comment: @Christer - there's no way to join on a field like this at runtime and even if you could, you probably wouldn't want to for performance reasons, as you've suggested. In reality, is the magnitude of click counts likely to be large in a small interval of time? If not, then bulk updating (with a scripted update) documents at regular intervals will work well, especially if the `modifier` on `field_value_factor` is logarithmic.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Russ! I 100% agree with what your saying!